# JSON API iphone

Tags: iphone, json

I need plenty of help in hanlding the JSON respond I will be getting through a web service API. It's forward geo-coding.

How do I get the number of results that was returned to me?
 Also getting the the value of the result, say the 'address'.

The respond JSON data is as follow. Thanks a lot.

```
[
{"total":63},{
    "t":"1",
    "lable":"Gek Poh Shopping Centre",
    "address":"762 Jurong West Street 75. (S)640762",
    "street":"Jurong West Street 75",
    "zip":"640762",
    "long":"103.6980151847",
    "lat":"1.348986165348",
    "x":"355149.0357","y":
    "149142.5301",
    "is_prem":"0",
    "pid":"47120",
    "aid":"115810",
    "lid":"245690",
    "has_biz":"1",
    "is_main_building":"1",
    "id":"245690",
    "cat_id":"80"
    },
    {
    "t":"1",
    "lable":"Gek Poh Ville Community Club (CC)",
    "address":"1 Jurong West Street 74. (S)649149",
    "street":"Jurong West Street 74",
    "zip":"649149",
    "long":"103.69890252806",
    "lat":"1.3489703630875",
    "x":"355247.7723",
    "y":"149140.7302",
    "is_prem":"0",
    "pid":"2979",
    "aid":"116734",
    "lid":"127311",
    "has_biz":"1",
    "is_main_building":"1",
    "id":"127311",
    "cat_id":"14"
    }
]
```

Comment: what does total key represent in your json..

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore. It's the result that the service have found. But it's not the actual number of results being returned back as there's a parameter to limit it.

Answer (score 3):

There's [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) just download it and copy all the files in SBJson Group to your project and include "SBJson.h"

If your JSON data is in a NSString (dataString), you can do this:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray *dataArray = [parser objectWithString:dataString];
for (NSDictionary *childDic in dataArray) {
  NSString *str = [childDic objectForKey:@"address"]; // Here you will get the address
}
```

Just a sample, Hope it helps

Comment: Of course, that example doesn't work in his case, where the outer entity is an array.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is quite simple do deal with, once you get the hang of it.  There are several JSON packages for iPhone, SBjson being one of the more popular ones.

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) consists of `values`, `objects`, and `arrays`.  In your example you have an array (denoted by the `[]` brackets) containing several objects (denoted by the `{}` brackets).  Each object, in turn, contains several name/value pairs.  With most iPhone JSON parsers the arrays will translate into NSArray objects and the objects will translate into NSDictionary objects.  Individual values (not surrounded by any brackets) come through as NSString (for quoted values) or NSNumber (for numerical values not within quotes).

Once you have the result of a JSON parse you "peel the onion" a layer at a time to find your data.

To find out which type you have at any layer use isKindOfClass:

```
if ( [anObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now I understand better. What different does the "total" has compared to "t" and "label". They are all objects, aren't they? Why are they enclosed by different {} bracket?

Comment: Notice that each {} object in your example is inside the [] brackets and separated from each other with a comma.  The {} objects are all distinct elements in the containing [] array.  What the individual objects mean is up to the person designing the protocol -- presumably, in this case, the first element in the array is always a special object containing a total count of some sort.  You need to refer to documentation on the specific protocol.